# A word for an evil thief, when read backwards, becomes valuable (by definition)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This word, that will take god's gift to you away from you,
when read backwards, is something of sentimental value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> KILLER and RELIC (by sound).

Because, firstly,

> a KILLER is someone who takes "god's gift to you" (life) away from you, an evil thief of life,

and secondly,

> a RELIC is something valuable, history giving it perhaps only sentimental value rather than use value.